# How to find the files being written between a time range in java in unix

Tags: java, unix

I have several files in a directory , I want to find the files which were written between a time range.
As I know its not possible to get create time of file in linux.

I can work out with sorting files with last modified time , is there any simpler way to do this ?

Comment: You could execute unix cmd in Java to find the last modified time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808039/file-modification-time-seconds-on-unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In case you mean implicitly for java solution:**

In Java, you can use the `File.lastModified()` to get the file’s last modified timestamps. This method will returns the time in **milliseconds** (long value, from epoch time), you may to format it with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to make it a human readable format.

So all you need to do is something like this:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        if(listOfFiles[i].lastModified() > FROM && listOfFiles[i].lastModified() < TO){
                doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: `FROM,TO` are of type long and represent a time stamp.